# Drag and drop in WinAppDriver doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, winappdriver

I try to automate tests of a drag and drop behavior in a WPF application. One custom control is dragged on another:

[image: manual drag and drop]

Drag and drop behavior implemented in [the usual WPF way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview):

```
<UserControl ...
             MouseMove="ToolboxModule_OnMouseMove">
```

```
private void ToolboxModule_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);

    var data = new DataObject();
    data.SetData("ModuleDescription", DataContext);

    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

```
<UserControl ...
             Drop="WorkspaceView_OnDrop" AllowDrop="True">
```

```
private void WorkspaceView_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var dropped = e.Data.GetData("ModuleDescription");
    var viewModel = (WorkspaceViewModel)DataContext;
    if (viewModel.ChainVm.AddModuleCommand.CanExecute(dropped))
        viewModel.ChainVm.AddModuleCommand.Execute(dropped);
}
```

But when I try to automate this with WinAppDriver, the drag and drop does not work. Cursor shape is not changed and nothing happens.

[image: WinAppDriver drag and drop]

I've tried several approaches:

*Actions Drag and Drop*

```
var moduleControl = mainWindow.GetToolboxModuleControl(moduleName);
var actions = new Actions(_session);
actions.DragAndDrop(moduleControl, mainWindow.WorkspaceControl).Perform();
```

*Actions click and hold*

```
var moduleControl = mainWindow.GetToolboxModuleControl(moduleName);
var actions = new Actions(_session);
actions.ClickAndHold(moduleControl).MoveByOffset(200, 0).Release().Perform();
```

*Driver mouse operations* (from [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/8bb91f06ef9cbc798c88099a586c15d74fd17870/Tests/WebDriverAPI/Mouse.cs#L117))

```
_session.Mouse.MouseMove(moduleControl.Coordinates, 50, 50);
_session.Mouse.MouseDown(null);
_session.Mouse.MouseMove(mainWindow.WorkspaceControl.Coordinates, 100, 100);
_session.Mouse.MouseUp(null);
```

*Driver mouse operations with delays*

```
_session.Mouse.MouseMove(moduleControl.Coordinates, 50, 50);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_session.Mouse.MouseDown(null);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_session.Mouse.MouseMove(mainWindow.WorkspaceControl.Coordinates, 100, 100);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
_session.Mouse.MouseUp(null);
```

Nothing works. Any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?

When I try to move the app window by dragging it's title bar via WinAppDriver, it successfully moves the window. So the dragging operations technically work, but not in the case of dragging a control within the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer.

WinAppDriver doesn't move the mouse, but "teleport" it. It means mouse cursor is not dragged all the way to the target with finite speed, it is being jumped from start to end position without any intermediate positions.

In this particular case it causes the problem. What actually happens:

1. Cursor teleported to the center of first element. MouseMove and
   other mouse movement events are firing on first element.
   `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method is not executed, because left mouse
   button is not pressed.
2. Left mouse button is pressed. MouseDown, Click and other related event are firing on first element. `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` method is
   not executed, because there is no mouse movement.
3. Cursor jumped to second element without touching the first. MouseMove and other mouse movement events are firing on second
   element only. Since no MouseMove event is firing on first element
   with left mouse button pressed, the drag and drop process never
   starts.

Solutions are simple: move the cursor within first element boundaries before jump to the second or change the event, where drag and drop process starts (MouseDown instead of MouseMove, for example). I chose  the latter:

```
<UserControl ...
             MouseDown="ToolboxModule_OnMouseDown">
```

```
private void ToolboxModule_OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);

    var data = new DataObject();
    data.SetData("ModuleDescription", DataContext);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Aleksei Petrov's answer best explains the problem. I am just sharing the working code based on that description.

```
public void DragAndDrop(WindowsElement source, WindowsElement target)
{
    // The most important part of the workaround is "MoveByOffset(10, 0)". WinAppDriver "teleports" mouse to target location 
    // when we call MoveToElement(). This means that the element being dragged will not be moved but just the mouse does.
    // To force the drag behavior, we need to move the mouse with in the source element's border first and
    // then move it to the target location.
    new Actions(WinAppDriver.Current)
        .ClickAndHold(source)
        .MoveByOffset(10, 0)
        .MoveToElement(target)
        .Release()
        .Build().Perform();
}
```