# Drag and Drop using Winapp driver for a UI Element

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, winappdriver

I have a plugin installed in visual studio that lets me create a form UI. Now I am trying to drag and drop an element on the form screen with help of an automation script using winapp driver which I am unable to do.

```
var FindVSProjectWindow = DesktopSession.FindElementByName("SystemModeler4 - Microsoft Visual Studio  (Administrator)");
            if (FindVSProjectWindow != null)
            {
                const int offset = 100;

                var FindAttribute = DesktopSession.FindElementByName("VsClassViewMembersPane").FindElementByName("Attribute1");

                DesktopSession.Mouse.MouseMove(FindAttribute.Coordinates);
                DesktopSession.Mouse.MouseDown(null); // Pass null as this command omit the given parameter
                DesktopSession.Mouse.MouseMove(FindAttribute.Coordinates, offset, offset);
                DesktopSession.Mouse.MouseUp(null); // Pass null as this command omit the given parameter
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
```

I tried this code using an example from github but not happening.

Comment: Maybe be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55282392/5380023

Answer (score 0):

Using `Mouse` and `Keyboard` is obsolete. You should update Appium to the latest version and use [`OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm) instead.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets an <see cref="T:OpenQA.Selenium.IMouse" /> object for sending mouse commands to the browser.
/// </summary>
[Obsolete("This property was never intended to be used in user code. Use the Actions or ActionBuilder class to send direct mouse input.")]
public IMouse Mouse
{
  get
  {
    return this.mouse;
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets an <see cref="T:OpenQA.Selenium.IKeyboard" /> object for sending keystrokes to the browser.
/// </summary>
[Obsolete("This property was never intended to be used in user code. Use the Actions or ActionBuilder class to send direct keyboard input.")]
public IKeyboard Keyboard
{
  get
  {
    return this.keyboard;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next IWebElement DragAndDrop [extension](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/1223#issuecomment-741770991) or new one if you need to use offset:

```
public void DragAndDropWithOffset(this IWebElement source, IWebElement destination, Point destinationOffset)
{
    var destinationCenterX = destination.Location.X + point.X;
    var destinationCenterY = destination.Location.Y + point.Y;
    var action = new Actions(source.GetDriver());
    action.MoveToElement(source).Build().Perform();
    action.ClickAndHold(source).MoveByOffset(destinationCenterX, destinationCenterY).Build().Perform();
    destination.Click();
    action.Release().Perform();
}
```